# If there is the inverse operator of the operator A, then $(A^{-1})^{-1}=A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

A friend of mine asked me today for this example:

If there is the inverse operator of the operator A, then $(A^{-1})^{-1}=A$?

But I do not have the ability to help, so I told him that his example will be posted on this site, and I am convinced that a number of colleagues will help us. I thank you for your answers preliminarily.

Comment: What kind of operator are we talking about? What are your spaces?

Comment: $A$ is a linear operator

Comment: It's defined as $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}=I$

Answer (score 0):

Be careful because some operators $A$ only have a right or left inverse and in this case it is not necessarily true that $(A^{-1})^{-1} = A.$  For example consider the Hilbert space $l_2$ of all square summable (complex) sequences.  Define $A : l_2 \to l_2$ by $A(a_1, a_2, a_3, ...) = (0,a_1, a_2, ...)$ the right shift operator.  Now it has a one sided inverse, namely the left shift operator, $B : l_2 \to l_2$ by $B(a_1, a_2, a_3, ...) = (a_2, a_3,...)$.  Clearly, $BA(a_1, a_2, ...) = (a_1, a_2, ...)$, so $BA = I$.  However, it is easy to see that $AB \neq I$.

If your operator $A$ comes from a group, then the statement is true.

Comment: But $B$ is not the inverse of $A$, so the hypotheses of the problem are not satisfied.

Comment: thanks sir, please help me for the last part, it is easy to see that $AB≠I$.

Comment: @  Jonas Meyer: i.e., The above solution is not correct

Comment: $AB(a_1, a_2, a_3,...) = A(a_2, a_3, ..) = (0, a_2, a_3, ..)$ so you lose the first coordinate.

Comment: can you please explain this to add to your solution to be more clear

Comment: @JonasMeyer ok fair enough.  I thought the user may not know about right and left inverses vs double sided inverses and this is why I posted the example.